# Math equations are not displayed in exported pdf?

Tags: php, jquery, yii2, mathjax, mpdf

I'm using yii2 mpdf extension for print page, and using "mathjax" plugin for write mathematical equations. Equations are displayed correctly in web page but not displayed in printed pdf.

[image]

Comment: It's lokk like missing font in pdf, Check what font use mathjax, then add it to pdf,

Comment: i'm using MODE_UTF8 in mPDF and mathjax configuration is https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mathjax/2.7.0/MathJax.js?config=TeX-MML-AM_CHTML , so i think and might confused javascript ignore at the time we export content to pdf.

Comment: Show your HTML and PHP code.

Comment: i am using yii2 mPDF plugin for printing content..